# Is PHP equipped for long-time execution such as web crawling & processing large files?

Tags: php

I once saw a post suggesting that PHP was originally built for merely showing static webpage, not for actual programming and therefore it has serious drawback in long time execution due to memory leakage.

I know PHP "can" be used to crawl dozens of web pages, process audio/video files etc but is it "good" at it? Of course judging whether it is good at something shall be a relative assessment. In this case, ASP/node.js/Python will be the comparisons.

Has PHP7.x been improved or adapted to long time execution?

This is a sort of question in general not the specific one. But I think this post may give useful insight to many people.

Comment: "**primarily opinion-based** Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Comment: ive had long jobs (week+) that I run in php with no issues. agree with the answer that running under apache is a different story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is not a bad choice for writing long-running processes, mostly the issues are that starting a long-running process from mod_apache or PHP-FPM gets overly complicated.

There are full Web servers, WebSocket servers, and more written in pure PHP, and are long-running, and work quite well, perhaps not as fast as Node.js or Python in their execution, but for network/database bound workloads I don't think there would be a significant difference.

If you are comfortable programming in PHP, then I would suggest using it would be a good choice to get started.

Some example of PHP based servers:

- https://reactphp.org/
- https://github.com/appserver-io/webserver

Both of those examples are non-blocking servers written in PHP.

Comment: Can I see some of those web servers written in PHP? I heard that built in server of PHP is single threaded and has poor performence so it cannot be used for real service.

Comment: Wondering, is https://github.com/appserver-io/webserver really **multithreaded** as claimed in their description? Is it possible to implement a php-only **multithreaded** application without additional extensions (`webserver` has none).

Comment: Command line PHP can fork, so yes you can, but you can't fork when running under Apache.

Comment: The built in webserver in PHP is not production ready at all.

Comment: I checked source - they use `reactphp` and in fact they only have asynchronous IO (at best), not multithreading.

Comment: @ChrisSeufert "Command line PHP can fork" --- only if you have `pcntl`, and that project does not have it as a dependency (nor anywhere in its code).

Comment: You could also use proc_open

Comment: @zerkms by itself it's not, but you can proc_open another PHP process to run Async and on another cpu core (like the way webworkers do)

Comment: Just FYI, appserver.io does require the pthreads PECL library, so this class can extend \Thread
https://github.com/appserver-io/server/blob/4adae077e7664739e0b061de0c1b432168a4f880/src/AppserverIo/Server/Workers/ThreadWorker.php

Comment: Thanks! So it was primarily the problem of web server after all